# Which is the referenced object of an interface variable containing an object of a class which implements the interface?

Tags: java, interface, object-reference

I have created a Motor class which implements the Measurable interface.
Then I create a variable of type Measurable called motorTemperature.

If I...

```
 Measurable motorTemperature = new Motor (x);
```

which will be the object referenced by motorTemperature? (Motor or Measurable type?

Comment: "which will be the object?" - the one you've created, which is `new Motor (x)`

Comment: motorTemperature is not a variable.  It is an object of type Measurable, and can be other things...  you could also have something like "Measurable motorTemperature = new Transmission(x);"... so naming it "motorTemperature" is probably not a good idea...  the temperature variable would be object_name.getTemperature();  if that's what the interface requires...

Comment: @pcalkins - motorTemperaure **is** a variable of type Measurable and as initialized above, it holds a value which is a reference to an object of type Motor.

Comment: right... but I wouldn't think of it or call it a variable... though I guess the pointer itself is a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
Measurable motorTemperature = new Motor(x);
```

we create an object of type Motor. It is a Motor and will remain a Motor.

The Motor implements the Measurable interface. We can therefore assign a reference to our Motor to a variable of type Measurable (and we in fact do so).  This does not change the fact that the Motor is a Motor.

However, since the only reference we have now got to our Motor is this Measurable, our only access to it can only speak in terms of what can be expressed via the Measurable interface.  We can't ask it about any Motor properties nor ask it to do Motor actions that are not defined as methods in Measurable.

P.S. whether or not motorTemperature is a good name for a Measurable is a separate question. If the only measurement available from a Motor is its temperature, that might make sense.  If we can call 'motorTemperature.getRPM()' then the name seems less appropriate.

Comment: "We can't ask it about any Motor properties nor ask it to do Motor actions that are not defined as methods in Measurable."  I don't think that's true.  It then has two types.... the object itself and the interface...  a Super call for instance...

Comment: In fact it's got at least three types... object, motor and measurable... it could also have others if more interfaces are implemented.  Some of this is linguistic trickery... is the reference to an object a variable? yes... but is an object a variable?  no... so the reference could also be called a variable of type pointer. and now I wonder if pointer methods could also be called? Not sure what the point would be....lol... I've gone down a rabbit hole.

Comment: If you try and call ```motorTemperature.someMotorMethod()``` you will get an undefined-method error from the compiler.  You can cast and call ```((Motor)motorTemperature).someMotorMethod()``` but that is a different matter: you're getting a Motor reference (which is obviously possible in this simple case) and then using the Motor reference to call a Motor method.  I don't see that "super call" comes into this anywhere; the superclass of Measurable is not Motor; Measurable has no superclass that we have been told of.  The superclass of Motor is (as far as we know) Object, not Measurable.

Comment: interesting... I did not know this...  I've guess I've never typed a class/object like this before.

Comment: Consider this uninitialized declaration: ```Measurable x;``` - I assume it's clear that ```x``` can only have type ```Measurable``` at this point?  And assigning some value to ```x``` does not change the type of ```x```.

Comment: oh I don't know... many different objects could implement Measurable... so once you assign it to an object, it has that type as well... (if Measurable is defined as an interface...) I still think we're in linguistic trickery land here.  I don't think calling a defined interface a "type" is quite correct... and it's not incorrect either

Comment: meaning that "type" can mean something else.... and mean there is only one "type" of a thing.  In Java one thing can have multiple types... so the question "what type is it?" should be maybe "what type or types"??   And it's a type of reference I guess...  but it's pointer to the object of a certain type...  maybe if we look at the pointer of a motor defined as motor as opposed to motor defined as measurable that would be more clear cut?

Comment: The way to resolve such questions is to read the defining document. [Here, for example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html) Is where the spec defines what is meant by 'type'.  Note the words 'every variable has a type' -- emphasis on 'a'.

Comment: well in this case it's multiple types... but again, meanings of these words are in question.... for instance, if a function took a type of Measurable, you could pass it Motor or Measurable... or any other object that implements Measurable, no?

Comment: if it's a single type, then maybe this would be "reference pointer" that points to a sort of dummy, shortened Motor class?  Motor class shortened to Measurable?  The fact that you can cast to Motor seems to imply that the whole Motor is still there, though.   I think an interface is still, at it's heart an abstract class without supers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194197/discussion-between-another-dave-and-pcalkins).